# Is true that $((A^\varepsilon)^c)^\varepsilon \subseteq A^c$, where $A^\varepsilon := \{x \in X \mid d(x,A) \le \varepsilon\}$?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X=(X,d)$ be a metric space. For a subset $A$ of $X$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, define the $\varepsilon$-enlargement of $A$ by $A^\varepsilon := \{x \in X \mid \text{dist}(x,A) \le \varepsilon\}$, where $\text{dist}(x,A) := \inf_{a \in A} d(x,a)$ is the distance of the point $x$ from the subset $A$. Finally, let $A^c := X\setminus A$ and define $A^{-\varepsilon} := ((A^c)^\varepsilon)^c$.

> **Question.** Is it always true that $A \subseteq (A^\varepsilon)^{-\varepsilon}$ ? Or equivalently, is it always true that $((A^\varepsilon)^c)^\varepsilon \subseteq A^c$ ?

## Notes

- I think the answer should be affirmative, but proving it is unncessarily tedious (to see the difficulty, just try to spell out the statement "$x \in ((A^\varepsilon)^c)^\varepsilon$").

## Edit: affirmative answer for modified definition of $A^\varepsilon$

Consider the **modified definition** $A^\varepsilon := \{x \in X \mid d(x,A) < \varepsilon\}$. It is an elementary result in real analysis that if $\emptyset \ne S \subseteq \mathbb R$ with $\inf S < u$, then there exists $s \in S$ such that $s < u$. Back to our problem, we deduce that
$$x \in ((A^\varepsilon)^c)^\varepsilon \implies d(x, (A^\varepsilon)^c) < \varepsilon \implies \exists y \in (A^\varepsilon)^c \mid d(x, y) < \varepsilon.
$$
On the other hand, if $x \in A$, then we'd have $d(x,y) \ge \varepsilon$ because $d(y,A) \ge \varepsilon$, since $y \in (A^\varepsilon)^c$. This contradicts $d(x,y) < \varepsilon$. We therefore conclude that $((A^\varepsilon)^c)^\varepsilon \subseteq A^c$.

## Open question

Consider the **original definition** $A^\varepsilon := \{x \in X \mid d(x,A) \le \varepsilon\}$. User **Kavi** has shown that the answer to the original claim if false in general.

> **Question.** What if $A$ is assumed to be open ?

Answer (score 2):

This is not true. Let $X=\mathbb R$ and $A=[0,1]$. Let us show that $0 \in ((A^{\epsilon})^{c})^{\epsilon}$. Since $0$ is not in $A^{c}$ this would give a counter-example to your claim.

First note that $-\epsilon -\frac 1 n \in (A^{\epsilon})^{c}$. ($A^{\epsilon} =[-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon]$]. Hence $dist(0, (A^{\epsilon})^{c}) \leq \epsilon +\frac 1 n$. Since $n$ is arbitrary we see that $dist(0, (A^{\epsilon})^{c}) \leq \epsilon$. This finishes the proof.

However the result is true if $B^{\epsilon}$ is defined as $\{x: dist(x,B) <\epsilon\}$.  Proof: Suppose, if possible, $x \in  ((A^{\epsilon})^{c})^{\epsilon}$ and $x \in A$. Then there exists $y \in (A^{\epsilon})^{c}$ with $d(x,y) <\epsilon$. But then $d(y,A)<{\epsilon}$  or $y \in A^{\epsilon}$  , a contradiction.

Comment: Is it true that $x\in A \cap ((A^\varepsilon)^c)^\varepsilon \Longleftrightarrow \operatorname{dist}(x, (A^\varepsilon)^c) = \varepsilon$?

Comment: Great answer thanks. It seems $0$ is an accumulation point of $A^c=(-\infty,0) \cup (1,+\infty)$. Maybe my claim true if $A$ is assumed to be open ?

Comment: BTW, why the "$1/n$" thing ? What's wrong with directly computing $A^\varepsilon = [-\varepsilon,1+\varepsilon] \implies (A^\varepsilon)^c = (-\infty,-\varepsilon) \cup (1+\varepsilon,+\infty) \implies d(0, (A^\varepsilon)^c) = \varepsilon$, and then concluding that $0 \in ((A^\varepsilon)^c)^\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong  with what you are saying but to prove that the distance is exactly $\epsilon$ using the definition  of distance from a point to a set you have to produce an element of the set. I am just making the argument a little more rigorous. May be I am too pedantic :-).

Comment: What about when $A$ is assumed **open**, i.e $A^c$ is assumed **closed** (see **Edit** to question) ?

Comment: @dohmatob My guess is that it is still false but I don 't have a counter-example. If $A$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$ then the result is true bit is seems doubtful in general.

Comment: OK, this is still open then. On another front, what if the definition of $A^\varepsilon$ is modified to $A^\varepsilon := \{x \in X \mid d(x,A) < \varepsilon\}$ ? Is the grand claim still false ? In particular, i think this should solve all the existence problems you mentioned.

Comment: The result is true and very easy to prove if you redefine it this way. @dohmatob

Comment: Indeed. It is an elementary result in real analysis that if $\emptyset \ne S \subseteq \mathbb R$ with $\inf S < u$, then there exists $s \in S$ such that $s < u$. We deduce that
$$x \in ((A^\varepsilon)^c)^\varepsilon \implies d(x, (A^\varepsilon)^c) < \varepsilon \implies \exists y \in (A^\varepsilon)^c \mid d(x, y) < \varepsilon.
$$
On the other hand, if $x \in A$, then we'd have $d(x,y) \ge \varepsilon$ because $d(y,A) \ge \varepsilon$, since $y \in (A^\varepsilon)^c$. This contradicts $d(x,y) < \varepsilon$. We therefore conclude that $((A^\varepsilon)^c)^\varepsilon \subseteq A^c$.